# Differences in expires_in cookies in Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, cookies

What is the difference between:

```
cookies[:login] = { :value => "XJ-122", :expires => 1.hour.from_now }
```

and

```
cookies[:login] = { :value => "XJ-122", :expires => 1.hour }
```

Aren't both times calculated at the time the cookie is set, and therefore 'from_now' is irrelevant?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can always check your understanding using "rails console".

```
$ rails c
Loading development environment (Rails 3.2.3)
1.9.2-p318 :001 > 1.hour
 => 3600 seconds 
1.9.2-p318 :002 > 1.hour.class
 => Fixnum 
1.9.2-p318 :003 > 1.hour.from_now
 => Fri, 25 May 2012 04:16:57 UTC +00:00 
1.9.2-p318 :004 > 1.hour.from_now.class
 => ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone
```

ActiveSupport::TimeWithZone is a 'glorified' Time class.

:expires needs a Time instance. So, you should use 1.hour.from_now